# Configuring two routers on my home network

Tags: router

A few months ago, I had a new router installed. The ISP took care of it. I'm not exactly sure how these routers are connected together. Pictured is the box (I'm guessing some kind of cheap switch) the cat 6 cables are connected to. Picture is below.

1. Yellow cable is WLAN.
2. Black cable goes to my upstairs router (has not wireless network).
3. Blue cable goes to my downstairs router (other blue cable goes to phone).

I'm trying to figure out how to get the two routers to play nice together. The black router has gateway of 10.0.0.1. Blue router gateway is 192.168.1.1. Blue router can see black router at 192.168.1.214. The blue router can somehow see one of the devices on 10.0.0.3 but not others. I don't know why.

I tried setting up a static route on the blue router to the black router.

- `Interface` set to `LAN`
- `Target` set to 10.0.0.0
- `Netmask` set to 255.255.255.0
- `Gateway` is set to 192.168.1.214

The static route is showing up on blue router but it still can't see the devices on 10.0.0.*

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: The pictured box looks like a mini patch panel – it just provides an independent jack for each of the blue cables. A switch would require a power supply. Could you clarify what sort of phone (and into what jack) the other blue cable goes to?

Comment: Could you also clarify what you mean by "router ... has gateway"? Do you mean those are the routers' _own_ addresses, rather than their configured gateway addresses?

Comment: One blue cable goes to phone modem. Other goes to the downstairs router. When I say it has a gateway, I mean it has a gateway IP. So my upstairs router, which is hardwired into my computer, has gateway ip of 10.0.0.1. The upstairs router connects to downstair router through 192.168.1.214.

Comment: What are the routers' _own_ IP addresses on both interfaces (each router's WAN address and LAN address)? And what kind of phone modem is that?

Comment: Upstairs router doesn't have a WAN address. Downstairs router has IP address provided by ISP. LAN address of upstairs router is 10.0.0.1 from within my upstairs. Downstairs router sees the upstairs router at 192.168.1.214. IP address of downstairs router is 192.168.1.1.

Comment: Are you having problems? If so, it would seem your ISP did something wrong since they set everything up, have you tried asking them for help? Some tech support departments are even open 24hrs, and you're paying them after all

Comment: So in other words, the upstairs router's LAN address is 10.0.0.1, WAN address is 192.168.1.214 (doesn't matter that it's not an Internet-facing port, the router still considers it to be the "WAN side"), and gateway address is 192.168.1.1. The downstairs router's LAN address is 192.168.1.1, WAN address is ISP-issued, gateway address is ISP-assigned... In your photo, which of the blue cables goes to the phone and which goes to the downstairs router?

Comment: Only problem I'm having is a I can't get port forwarding working on a machine that is upstairs, connected to the upstairs router.

Comment: Everything you restated is correct. I have no idea which blue wire goes to phone device and which goes to router. I guess I'd have to unplug one of them and see.

Comment: What has me really confused is that the downstairs router *can* forward to one of the machines on the 10.* upstairs network. And it shows it as a listed, known device. It's a Windows machine hardwired into the upstairs router, no wifi. This is not the case on my mac, which is both hardwired into the upstairs router and gets wifi from downstairs router. I have a synology NAS drive which is also hardwired to upstairs router. The downstairs router shows it as a device I can port forward to as well.

Comment: I think I might see the problem. The downstairs router has the mac address for the port for my my mac's ethernet in the "ARP table." Not sure how to delete that, though.

Comment: OK, rebooted the router which got rid of the old IP address for my mac. Then I opened up a DMZ for ip address  of 192.168.1.214 (the black router's ip address) and now port forwarding is working for my mac. Thanks for listening.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up moving the upstairs router from "Router mode" to "Bridge mode." Things work much more smoothly now than having the routers on two different networks. Now every device, including the bridged router, has an IP of 192.168.1.*.

IMPORTANT NOTE: You don't use the WAN port when the router is in bridge mode. All devices get plugged directly into the LAN ports. Took me a few minutes to figure that out.